# Can $x^2+xy+y^2$ be written using only $x-y$?

Tags: polynomials

My question is very specific and as such: Can $x^2+xy+y^2$ be written using only $x-y$, that is, as a function of $x-y$? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close with reading the comments.   Also, you have to put `$` signs around the math expressions for the formatting to work.

Answer (score 4):

No, it can't.

Suppose such a function F existed. Then for all x,y we would have $x^2+xy+y^2=F(x-y)$.

But then when $x=y$, we would have $3x^2=F(0)$, which is impossible. The LHS isn't constant while the RHS is.

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments, the previous argument doesn't work if the field is of characteristic $3$. In fact, the statement is true:  in a field of characteristic $3$, we have $1=-2$, so $x^2+xy+y^2=x^2-2xy+y^2=(x-y)^2$.

Comment: For $3=0$, e.g. in the field $\Bbb F_3$ this is no contradiction.